# SQL to find the number of rows per table in a database

Tags: sql-server-2012, rowcount

My goal is to create a spreadsheet of all the tables in the current database that will display the table name and the number of rows in each table. A bonus would be to also be able to display when anything was last entered or changed in the table. I'm not sure if the last part is possible though.

This is what I have so far... its nothing much but I just can't beat my head around how to add the per table row count to it.

```
SELECT name, type, type_desc
FROM [scheme].sys.all_objects
WHERE type = 'U'
```

Comment: Do all the tables have the same schema? The column names are the same?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK yes, they all do have the same schema. I just replace the [scheme] with my database name. We have a silly amount of tables in it, we basically want to get a list of the tables with data to see if it is even being used. They also don't have the same column names unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query against the system catalog views:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

to get the desired result - all tables in the current database, and the number of rows in each.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly and surprisingly quicker than I expected. Just a question, is it at all possible to get the date time when any modification was made to any table in a database?

Comment: @5tar-Kaster: no, that timestamp is not stored by SQL Server and is not available.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(TABLENAME VARCHAR(100) ,
COUNT INT)
INSERT INTO #T
EXEC SP_MSFOREACHTABLE 'SELECT ''?'' ,COUNT(*) FROM ?'
SELECT * FROM  #T
DROP TABLE #T
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers and instead provide an explanation as to what your code does

Comment: This does work 100% its a touch slower than the above answer by @marc_s but it still works, thank you